# How to put special characters in variable and use them in string?

Tags: string, bash, variables

I'm wondering is there anyway to use for example `,` or `^` or `%` and so on, from variables in Bash ?

in instance I have three variables

```
var1='hello world'
var2=${var1:3}
var3='^'
```

I want to do this in bash ! please attention to my question I know it's very simple in other ways but how about this ?

```
echo ${var1:0:3}${var2$var3} # instead of echo ${var1:0:3}${var2^}
```

and finally output is :

```
heLlo world
```

Comment: Case modification expansion is done before variable expansion.

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve ? You can use `eval`, but this may bring security problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, `eval` can do execute arbitrary code, but has many security issues, so it should be used as last resort. Use it only when you trust the input 100%.

```
var1='hello world'
var2=${var1:3}
var3='^'

eval echo '${var1:0:3}${var2'$var3'}'
```

Comment: thnx yes eval is evil  and it's dangerous, repp ++ I'm waiting for other possible ways ...